# SQLite БД на сетевом диске. Connection.Open() - ошибка?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите как правильно написать путь к БД лежащей в сети?

```
SQLiteConnection ConnNE2006 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=\\VAIO\Users\Public\Downloads\testdb.sqlite; Version=3; ReadOnly=True;");
ConnNE2006.Open();
```

такая запись выдает ошибку "*unable to open database file*" при том что проводником по данному пути файл есть...

Comment: а текст ошибки предлагается угадать? добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос хотябы

Comment: Извиняюсь. Добавил. Как я понимаю я как то не так путь сетевой указал (с локальным путем так все ок)

Comment: попробуйте так @"Data Source=\\\\VAIO\Users\Public\Downloads\testdb.sqlite; Version=3; ReadOnly=True;" Взято [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18506097/5796587)

Comment: Плюсую коммент выше и хотел бы добавить, а доступ у Вас есть туда? Ну, вдруг там антивирус какой блокирует Ваше подключение или попросту доступа нет.

Comment: Да действительно дело оказалось в недостающих \\\\, Спасибо!

Comment: запости ответ и отметь как решенный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так @"Data Source=\\VAIO\Users\Public\Downloads\testdb.sqlite; Version=3; ReadOnly=True;"

Спасибо **rdorn**